# How can I use the GitHub REST API to get to the detail of the event that triggered a workflow run?

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I'm trying to use the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) to find the details of the event that triggered a workflow run, but can't find the link between the resources available in the set of API endpoints.

(Note that this is not within the context of a workflow run itself, it's after the fact, from the command line.)

### Example

As an example, [this workflow run](https://github.com/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/actions/runs/5253254871), number 52, was triggered by the [labeling of issue 5](https://github.com/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/issues/5), specifically where it was labeled with `contribution`.

[image: a screenshot of the specific workflow run UI on GitHub]

Although this labeling took place at the same time as another labeling event, I can conclude that it was the `contribution` label assignment specifically that was the event that triggered this particular workflow run as it's the only run in [all of the issue-triggered runs for this workflow](https://github.com/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/actions/workflows/community-id-requester.yaml?query=event%3Aissues) that

1. relates to the issue in question ([Feedback for "Prepare Your Project for Exchanging Data with Your Space"](https://github.com/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/issues/5))
2. wasn't skipped due to the `if` condition in the single job in the workflow definition that [checks that the label assigned is `contribution`](https://github.com/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/actions/runs/5253254871/workflow#L33).

### Data available from the API

Digging into the data, I can see the events for issue 5 thus:

```bash
gh api \
  repos/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/issues/5/events \
  | jq -r '
      sort_by(.created_at)[]
      | [.id, .created_at, .event, .label.name // "N/A"]
      | @tsv
    ' \
  | column -t
```

This emits (with my arrow added):

```
9257336498  2023-05-16T12:10:11Z  assigned    N/A
9257337593  2023-05-16T12:10:18Z  labeled     follow-up-with/dev
9257337604  2023-05-16T12:10:18Z  labeled     in-discussion
9350701703  2023-05-26T13:11:24Z  unassigned  N/A
9350745853  2023-05-26T13:16:10Z  unlabeled   follow-up-with/dev
9350745859  2023-05-26T13:16:10Z  unlabeled   in-discussion
9350745865  2023-05-26T13:16:10Z  labeled     needs-more-info
9399724555  2023-06-01T07:54:23Z  assigned    N/A
9399860518  2023-06-01T08:06:51Z  labeled     size/s
9512993115  2023-06-13T08:43:36Z  unlabeled   needs-more-info
9512993122  2023-06-13T08:43:36Z  labeled     contribution          <--
9512993130  2023-06-13T08:43:36Z  labeled     type/clarity
9512998765  2023-06-13T08:44:02Z  closed      N/A
```

So it's event ID 9512993122 that I'm looking for, somehow. But when I look through the [Workflow runs API endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28) I cannot find any endpoint that gives me a response where the data returned points anywhere to an event ID.

For example, if I look at [the workflows for the repo](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-workflows) I can discern that the ID of the workflow that I'm interested in is 47098817, via:

```bash
gh api \
  repos/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/actions/workflows \
  | jq '
      .workflows[]
      | select(.path | contains("community-id-requester")).id
    '
# returns 47098817
```

### No event data for the given workflow run

However when I then plug this workflow ID into the [Workflow runs API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-workflow), (and also manually narrow it down to the actual workflow run number 52 in question) ... there's nothing in the response that seems to link back to the triggering event.

There's a lot of data that comes back, so here's just the top level property names in the response - no sign of any trigger or event information:

```bash
gh api \
  repos/SAP-docs/sap-datasphere/actions/workflows/47098817/runs \
  | jq -c '
      .workflow_runs[]
      | select(.run_number == 52) 
      | keys
    '
```

This gives:

```json
[
  "actor",
  "artifacts_url",
  "cancel_url",
  "check_suite_id",
  "check_suite_node_id",
  "check_suite_url",
  "conclusion",
  "created_at",
  "display_title",
  "event",
  "head_branch",
  "head_commit",
  "head_repository",
  "head_sha",
  "html_url",
  "id",
  "jobs_url",
  "logs_url",
  "name",
  "node_id",
  "path",
  "previous_attempt_url",
  "pull_requests",
  "referenced_workflows",
  "repository",
  "rerun_url",
  "run_attempt",
  "run_number",
  "run_started_at",
  "status",
  "triggering_actor",
  "updated_at",
  "url",
  "workflow_id",
  "workflow_url"
]
```

(The value for the `event` key here is just the literal string `"issues"`. I had got excited when I saw that key, but that quickly turned to disappointment.)

I apologise for the lengthy description, but I would very much appreciate any pointers. What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: You could look at `github.event`, or inspect the JSON file at `$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH`, no?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not in the context of a workflow run itself (so I don't have access to those artifacts). I've added a note to clarify the context.

Answer (score 0):

About what triggered the workflow, you gave the answer already:

> As an example, this workflow run, number 52, was triggered by the labeling of issue 5

In your workflow file, you specified the trigger:

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [labeled]
  issues:
    types: [labeled]
```

In the workflow you refer to, it says at the top `Triggered via issue last week \ CindyVenet labeled #5` so that triggered the workflow:

[image]

So... isn't that proof enough what triggered the workflow? Maybe there is no API to find this out without the UI? What's the use case or what other information you're looking for?

The [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issues) doesn't provide any pointers how to check the triggering event using the GitHub REST API.

Comment: I am trying to find this out definitively, consistently and programmatically, after the fact. In other words, the REST API seems the right place to do it, as it has everything else. So thanks, but no, looking at the GUI isn't proof enough, unfortunately :-(